# Create script to copy from sheet1 to sheet1 daily pasting vaules in next column over

Tags: excel, vba

I am using this code below it is currently copying the data as intended. What I am looking to do is modify this so that it will copy the same source range every day but paste to 1 column over each time its ran. In the sheet I am trying to copy the daily count every day to this section called weekly counts per day. So when I run this on Tuesday, Tuesdays data will be entered in the column for Tuesday and so on. Then at the end of the week I just want it to overwrite what is in that Weekly column with new data. Any help or input is greatly appreciated.
[image: Daily Report]

```
Option Explicit
Sub MoveDataFromDailyReport()

Dim DB As Worksheet, SH As Worksheet
Dim TargetRow As Long, Index As Long
Dim SourceArr As Variant, DestArr As Variant
Dim Source As Range, Dest As Range

'set references up-front
Set SH = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Report")
Set DB = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Daily Report")
With DB
    TargetRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End With
SourceArr = Array("A4:B4", "A5:B5", "A6:B6")
DestArr = Array("H14:I14", "H15:I15", "H16:I16")

'loop through the source array, copying cell values to DB sheet
For Index = LBound(SourceArr) To UBound(SourceArr)
    Set Source = SH.Range(SourceArr(Index))
    Set Dest = DB.Range(DestArr(Index) & TargetRow)
    Source.Copy
    Dest.PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
Next Index

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken to get what you want, maybe something like this ?

```
Sub test()
Dim dt As String: dt = Format(Date, "dddd")
Dim EmpLoc As Range
Dim DC As Range

With Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set EmpLoc = .Range("A4:A6")
    Set DC = EmpLoc.Offset(0, 1)

    If .Range("H14").Value = "" Then _
    .Range("H14").Resize(DC.Rows.Count, 1).Value = EmpLoc.Value

    .Range("I13:N13").Find(dt, lookat:=xlWhole).Resize(DC.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = DC.Value
End With

'additional code
DC.ClearContents 'remove this line if cell B4:B6 doesn't need to be cleared

End Sub
```

What the code do :
Have the today-date's name into dt variable
Have range A4:A6 into EmpLoc range variable
Have range B4:B6 into DC (daily count) range variable
Check, if range("H14") is empty - put EmpLoc value to this range.
Put DC value under the row of the found cell which contains dt value.

So if for example that today is Thursday,
and when you open the workbook the beginning condition is exactly like in your image attachment, the macro will put B4:B6 value to the rows under the Thursday column.

Comment: I will give this a shot when I log back in to my computer in the morning. Just to clarify in cell A1 contains the date the data is from in cells b4,5,6 if that helps or changes anything for your code?

Comment: Hey Karma I want to give you a overview of what I am doing as I think what you posted will work. So I have a master daily report, that is like the above. I have 4 sheets connected to DB that get populated every morning with yesterdays data. When I look at my report that comes out tomorrow its going to contain data from 3-9-2022. the info in B4:B6 is done with countifs from employee sheet same on contractors. I have a PS script that I run to open master refresh data wait then run macro to copy sheet Daily Report to new workbook with A1's date and daily report as filename.

Comment: So this works I changed date to date -1 and it works how I would expect it to. My question is what happens on the following Monday are we just going to overwrite Sunday or is there some way to say if M-S is filled in delete everything in that range when the new week starts?